# PARSE DASHBOARD unable to see cloud logs after upgrading dashboard

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

After updating my parse-dashboard i lost the "logs column" as you can see:[image: Log missing]

I just upgraded my parse-dashboard and my parse server:

dashboard: ?.?.? (package.json https://pastebin.com/KRFaxJha)

parse-server: 2.4.0

node: 7.10.0

This is my parse-dashboard configuration file:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
          "appId": "APP_ID",
          "masterKey": "MASTER_KEY",
          "restKey": "REST_KEY",
          "serverURL": "http://WWW_WEBSITE:8081/parse",
          "appName":"APP_NAME"
        }
  ],
 "users": [
        {
          "user": "ADMIN",
          "pass": "ADMINXXXXXXX"
        }
 ]
}
```

This is my cloud code test function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

When i call it with a curl i have:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REST_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ }' http://WWW_WEBSITE:8081/parse/functions/hello

{"result":"Hello world!"}
```

the result is correct and on the parse server i have the trace:

```
verbose: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/functions/hello: {} method=POST, url=/parse/functions/hello, user-agent=curl/7.29.0, host=WWW_WEBSITE:8081, accept=*/*, x-parse-application-id=APPID, x-parse-rest-api-key=REST_KEY, content-type=application/json, content-length=3,
info: Ran cloud function hello for user undefined with:
  Input: {}
  Result: "Hello world!" functionName=hello, , user=undefined
verbose: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/functions/hello: {
  "response": {
    "result": "Hello world!"
  }
} result=Hello world!
```

I have seen this topic:
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard/issues/281
and i have try to set the verbose export variable on my parse-server and dashboard

i think i have miss some configuration but i can't find which one,

Thanks a lot,

Canna

Answer (score 0):

Bad dashboard version i don't know why:

npm install -g parse-dashboard fix it and installed the good dashboard version